# Extracting a part of 10K annual statement with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I have struggling at this for weeks now. I'm trying to work 10K annual statements of companies. I've downloaded the file from SEC's FTP server and this is how it looks like [10K](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/867665/000086766513000012/0000867665-13-000012.txt). It's an HTML file. So I've written the following code to convert it into text:

```
actvtxt=open("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\10Ks\\AbraxasPetroleum10K.txt",'r')  
txt=actvtxt.readlines()
ind=txt.index('<DOCUMENT>\n')
txt=txt[ind:]
x=(str.join('\n',map(str,txt)))
soup=BeautifulSoup(x.encode('utf-8'))
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
script.extract()    
text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
```

After getting the text I need to extract the text of

> 'Item 7 :Management’s Discussion and Analysis of Financial Condition and Results of Operations'.

This link will give you an idea of what I'm talking about: [actual 10K](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/867665/000086766513000012/axas12311210k.htm#item7)

I tried the following code:

```
substr=re.search(r'The following is a discussion of our consolidated financial condition(\s+|\w+|[#!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@^_`{|}]){1,}',text)
substr.group(0)
```

But this just gives me the start of the paragraph:

```
     u'The following is a discussion of our consolidated financial condition, results of operations, liquidity and capital resources. This discussion excludes the operations of Blue Eagle, except our equity share of Blue Eagle'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use beautifulsoup to do more of the work, why are you trying to extract all text and then parse that with re?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I was thinking of that. But if you look, the reference tag  for 'Item 7' it's connected with 'name' and 'ref' attributes. I don't know how to connect those. Plus, I'm going to extract that text for hundreds of document's and the reference tag have different names for each of them. So I'm still at odds as to how to do that

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  could you please elaborate?